# Transfer data between BroadCast and Activity

Tags: android

how can i transfer data from BroadcastReceiver to activity?
I tried it with intent but it's returning null.

```
MyBroadcastReceiver class:

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ......................................
            ......................................

        String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, CalendarCall.class);
        i.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
            (startActivity(i)-> i can't start Activity under BroadcastReceiver,what is another way to do that? )
        Log.d(TAG, phoneNumber);
                }
         }
}

}
```

Main Activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
        String number = intent.getStringExtra("number");
        Log.d(TAG, "Number: " + number);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MyBroadcastReceiver class:

public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final String TAG = "MyBroadcastReceiver";
    @Override
       public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ......................................
            ......................................

        String phoneNumber = extras.getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Intent i = new Intent(context, CalendarCall.class);
        i.putExtra("number", phoneNumber);
        context.startActivity(i);
        Log.d(TAG, phoneNumber);
                }
         }
}

}
```

**try this code**

Comment: Activity context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag

Comment: There is no need if you have need of that then you can set i.setFlag(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Comment: i added i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); but it is again returning null

Comment: if i don't add flag,there is error: AndroidRuntime(343): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver org.example.calendarcall.MyBroadcastReceiver: android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag.